# Why keyboard appear after the TabBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, tabbar, tabwidget

In My application there is tabBar and the Edittext.

See below image:

Normal Screen:

[image]

And Image After press on edittext:

[image]

Now why this tabbar goes up with the keyboard.
I want it to be remain fix at the bottom even if the user open the keyboard by pressing on edittext.

So what should i have to do ?

Please help e for that ?

My xml Layout for the TabBarMain activity is like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

      <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

So please help me for that.

Thanks.

Comment: after adding the `adjustPan` doesn't your EditTextView disappear from the screen on top, please let me know how you resolved this.

Comment: I've tried the solutions you've accepted but it is also hiding I mean shifting layout upwards. It's urgent to me.... How to fix this???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please use this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in android menifest.xml file in your activity.

Example..

```
<activity
            android:name="Youractivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

set the following in your TabHost

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

add stateUnchanged in your activity attribute windowsoftinputmode in manifest file, as below:

```
 <activity android:name="Youractivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"/>
```